# Drop all databases based on age

Tags: sql-server

How can we drop all databases based on age.

If i go with today's date with 2 months retention the list will come with below query , now i want to drop all the databases with query output.

```
SELECT name as [database] , database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases where create_date  <= '20190726' AND name NOT IN ('Master','Model','MSDB','tempdb')
```

#### Error

The below script not working with errors being:

> DROP DATABASE VM_P
>   Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 15
>   Could not find stored procedure 'DROP DATABASE VM_P.

#### Script

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR (64)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR (255)
DECLARE DROPDB CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE create_date  <= '20190726' 
AND name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB')

OPEN DROPDB
FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName
            PRINT @SQL
    EXEC @SQL
    FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE DROPDB
DEALLOCATE DROPDB
```

Comment: This is incredibly dangerous!  
Yes, you absolutely have to manage the old dross that people spin up and forget about but don't base your deletion criteria solely on the database's /creation/ date.  A long-running development project might easily take more than the three months you're allowing and then you're going to blithely trash all of that work.  (Hope your backups are all in order). 
Find a way to check if the database is being used before trashing it.

Comment: Thanks for the input Phill but this was accepted by the application team who creates databases, these were timebound job-related databases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is very, very close to working.

It's not explicitly clear from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) but the examples do show this.

When using `EXEC` (or `EXECUTE`) with a stored procedure, you write the object name straight after the statement (example 1 below), however when calling a T-SQL string you must include brackets (example 2 below)

**Example 1**

```
EXEC dbo.Procedure
```

**Example 2**

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable')
```

As such, your solution should look like this (Note the replacement of the static date with `GETDATE()` to satisfy your original condition of dropping based on the age of the database):

```
--For internal objects, always use NVARCHAR - this is what the engine uses internally in most places
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR (64)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (255)
DECLARE DROPDB CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
--Use GETDATE() with DATEADD for -60 days to get the threshold for deletion
WHERE create_date  <= DATEADD(DD,-60,GETDATE())
AND name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB')

OPEN DROPDB
FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName)
            PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE DROPDB
DEALLOCATE DROPDB
```

As an aside, given that this is such a potentially damaging script, I'd drop the `EXEC` and simply copy the printed statements into a new query to run them. This would avoid any unforeseen accidents as it gives you an opportunity to audit the script before you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a small changes in your script

Replace EXEC @SQL with   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL or EXEC (@SQL)
This works fine

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR (64)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR (256) 
DECLARE DROPDB CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE create_date  <= '20190726' 
AND name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB')

OPEN DROPDB
FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName
            PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL --OR EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE DROPDB
DEALLOCATE DROPDB
```